# how to configure Adobe CQ5 CRXDe site on IIS Server?

Tags: iis, adobe, aem, jcr, crx

I have created Author instance for Adobe CQ5 using CRXDe Editor it working successfully, now want to publish it on IIS Server,

i have also download Dispatcher for Windows OS and configured it with IIS, now i'm missing one which is how to host CQ5 site on IIS, Author instance is working properly. can someone suggest me how can i host this CRXde CQ5 site on IIS Server.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Do you have a publish instance set up as well?  The publish instance sits behind the dispatcher.  Author publishes its content to the publish instance.  The Dispatcher acts as a cachinglayer for the publish instance.

Comment: I have installed publish instance for CQ5 site and also configure dispatcher with publish instance but here i'm confused how i determine dispatcher is working or not for publish instance.

Comment: What happens when you make a page request to the dispatcher?  Is the request going back to publish or is it grabbing a cached version of the page?  Is it even getting that far?

Comment: i have configured dispatcher with IIS it is perfect now when i open publish instance with dispatcher that time it showing 500 internal error.

Comment: Is there anything showing in your publish error log?

Comment: @Woodifer thanks for your time, now i switch for Apache Web Server to configure dispatcher and it is working for me.